# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and assume the eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, what does that tell us about the kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we assume that $A$ has an eigenvalue of $\lambda = 0$, then what does that tell us about the kernel of $A$? Or more specifically, what does it tell us about the dimensions of the kernel of $A$.

I need someone to explain in detail please.

Comment: It shows that the dimension is at least one.

Comment: Downvote purely on the title of the question.  @LordSharktheUnknown has answered your question

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you explain in more detail?

Comment: If $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue, then there is a nonzero eigenvector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x = 0\cdot x = 0$. Hence $x$ belongs to the kernel of $A$. Since $x\neq 0$, the kernel has a nonzero element, so its dimension is at least one.

Comment: Would the same logic apply for $\lambda$ = 1? or any other eigenvalue? as long as a matrix has at least one eigenvalue, then the dimension of the kernel is at least one?

Comment: No. The identity matrix has $1$ as its only eigenvalue, but the kernel has dimension $0$.

Comment: Is the identity matrix the only exception for having dimension 0 and eigenvalue 1 ?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master For $\lambda  = 1$ you have $\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A - I) \ge 1$. In general, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $\dim\operatorname{Ker}(A - \lambda I) \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a matrix is just a linear transformation. Now a linear transformation is invertible if and only if it is full rank. This is equivalent to $\text{ker}(T) = \{0\}$, as well as $\text{det}(T) \neq 0$. Now $\text{det}(T) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}$, where $\lambda_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$. So if an eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$, then $T$ is not invertible. Thus, $\text{ker}(T)$ is non-trivial, and so has dimension at least $1$.